# Why can't I see the right side of my activity on my phone?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm trying to code an app for a school project. I'm stuck with the design. I can't see the right side of my activity on my phone, but it's appearing on the Android Studio preview. It's possible that my code isn't right or that i've didn't respect something.

And here are the 2 screenshots:
Android Studio Preview:
https://pasteboard.co/I6uT89f.png

Phone view:
https://pasteboard.co/I6uSgpW.jpg

Here's the code:

activity_main.xml

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialOverlayLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="#131313"/>

        <com.leinardi.android.speeddial.SpeedDialView
            android:id="@+id/speedDial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:sdMainFabClosedSrc="@drawable/ic_menu"
            app:sdOverlayLayout="@id/overlay"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/header2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/plante1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo_shape">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <fr.visufo.titouan.jardin.UnderlinedTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Plante 1"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_light"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:underlineColor="#6DB85C"
                    app:underlineWidth="10px"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Pensez à rentrer votre plante demain"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_light"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="335dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/degrees_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="0°C"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#636363"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        There are 8 similar relative layouts showing quite the same thing, here's 
        only one


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why do you use a relative layout for every view? You can achieve your design using only one relative layout.

Comment: You are probably getting into trouble with all the margins that you set. You applied the margins in the designer but when you moved to the phone with a different size screen the margins don't work out the way they did in the designer. I would consider simplifying the layout and use relative positioning in `RelativeLayout` or even `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Each row is a `RealtiveLayout` that contents subviews or group views. However, these children views don't have a relation with each other or parent. I suggest you need to update the relationship between these children views and parent. Otherwise, you can use the `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@titouan-pellerin - Unlike using `div` as a container for (most) things as in Website Design, you don't need to be repeatedly wrapping each individual view inside of it's own layout..
For Example, if I wanted to my activity to vertically show something like this:
(Title)
(some smaller subtext)
(An Image)
(Some Description text)
(And two buttons at the bottom)
..I wouldn't wrap each of these things individually in their own layout - I would simply create **1** base layout (to act as the main container), and then inside of it, I would create **1** vertical layout  for the content (arranged vertically), and **1** horizontal layout for the Buttons at the bottom (arranged horizontally).
Of course you will also want to set your margins according to how you want everything displayed.
You are most likely experiencing issues due to a mixture of margins getting added together over and over again and expanding past the screen's boundaries, combined with the fact that the phone is likely of different pixel density and resolution compared to the emulator.
**Step 1:** Fix your Layout, as I described above.
**Step 2:** Choose/Setup an Emulator that matches your Device most closely in Resolution/PixelDensity.
Hope this helps!
If you found this to be a good explanation, please **accept** this as the answer to your question.
Thanks, and happy coding!